# Enumerating processes that record or playback on Windows XP

Tags: winapi, process, windows-xp, audio, wdk

I would like to enumerate all processes, which have an open handle for any of the soundcards in the system. Ideally I would like a "process - sound card - action" relation, where action might be playback or record.

Is there a Win32 API for getting this information on Windows XP? Does this API work also on newer versions of Windows?

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly find out which handles are open in a process by analyzing its memory. Enumerating processes is done using

```
EnumProcesses()
```

You can then use the system API (brought to you by the DDK only, unfortunately)
If you want some more info (as I'm sure you do) here's a really useful thread.

[Sysinternals](http://forum.sysinternals.com/topic3577_post55733.html)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The Sysinternals thread shows a way to enumerate all handles a process has, using the Windows Driver Development Toolkit. I am such a newbie to DDK, that I just used Process Explorer to have a look at the handles a media player has. Now I am completely confused by file names like "\Device\KSENUM#xxx\{some GUID}". I guess this task has grown out of my competence.

Comment: I'd assume it's not TOO difficult to find out what the device is. Just look it up in the registry if you're interested. It requires a bit of research but I'm certain you'll be able to find out what you need. Also, the DDK stuff you see there is pretty much cut and paste stuff. It shouldn't be too difficult for you to just place your own code in the handle finding function.